# Printing multiply copies of Word document from WPF/C# .NET 4

Tags: wpf, printing, .net-4.0, ms-word

I'm building an WPF application in C# and .NET 4 and need to print out two copies of the same file.
I have the following code, which gets the job done, but it's not that pretty as Word opens up twice.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = invoiceFileAbsoluteStoreagePath;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        //Print out two copies - ugly! - no better way apparently
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        //Let's do it again... there need to be a better way :(
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Can't I somehow send an argument to Word letting it know that I want X copies from this document?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do my printing via WPF flow documents.  From there you can just create the WPF page, invoke the print command on it, auto fill the number of copies and execute the print job.  If you only have a few documents you can recreate them in XAML and even inject data into them.  It is a little time consuming to start, but once implemented, it is quite fast.  No opening word.  Just opening a xml file as a XamlDocument, inject data via ViewModel, and printing.

While [**this**](http://www.bradcurtis.com/2010/02/06/document-and-report-generation-using-xaml-wpf-databinding-and-xps/) is not specifically about flow documents, it will get you there.

Comment: Thanks, but to be frankly, it seems like a lot of work to print one single Word (.docx) file. I have a "template" .docx file, which I fill out and save on the HDD. After that I need to print the file out twince - that's it. Your suggestion seem to do much more dynamic stuff.

Comment: I implemented that for a project that I worked on a while back.  We had 3 documents (started as one).  It took me about 2 hours to create teh document templates in WPF, another hour to do the VMs and print code.  After timing the startup of Word, and print process we were using (about 6 seconds) times 40 times per day times 260 working days a year, I came up with 17 hours used.  The new process had a print job running to the printer almost instantly (less than 1/8th second), saving most of that 17 hours.  I made it pretty modular so that additional docs could be added later saving more...